# Display JQuery data in HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using jQuery to display messages from database , this is the jquery file:

```
function call() {
    $(".message_box").fadeIn();
    return false;
}
    function updatess() {
         $.getJSON("php/fetch.php", function(data) {
           $.each(data.result, function(){
            var message = this['message'];
            call();  
            $('div.message').html( message ); 
      });
     });
    }
```

and this is the HTML file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd" >
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Sample Chat Application</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="my_js.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<div class="message_box"> // some css like displayed:none; ......
        <div class="message"></div>
</div>  
  </body>
    </html>
```

but the problem is that if there is two messages , it display just the latest message , and if there are a lot of messages , every time new message comes it replace the old one . but i want all messages to be displayed. for example if i receive 3 messages i want 3 boxes appear not just one . when i use append instead of html ,all messages appears in one box.

Comment: `$('div.message').append( message ); ` and before `each` loop `$('div.message').empty();`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `append` method instead of the `html` method which overwrites the previous content:

```
function updatess() {
     $.getJSON("php/fetch.php", function(data) {
         // calling `.empty()` before the `.each()` call
         var $div = $('div.message').empty();
         $.each(data.result, function() {
            var message = this['message'];
            $div.append( message ); 
         });
    });
}
```

Note that I have used the `.empty()` method for removing the old content before the `.each()` call, if that's not what you want and you want to keep the current content, you can remove the `.empty()` method.

edit: For creating and appending a `div` element with class of `message` for each message:

```
$.each(data.result, function() {
     $(document.createElement('div'))
          .addClass('message')
          .html(this['message'])
          .appendTo('.message_box');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're replacing the HTML in your div every iteration with this line:

```
$('div.message').html( message );
```

You could wrap the message in another div and then append it instead:

```
var message = $('<div></div>').html(this['message']); 
$('div.message').append( message );
```

After edit:

If you want a new message box for each item, you'll need to create a new message box for each item.

Try this:

```
function addMessage(message) {
    var messageBox = $('<div></div>').addClass('message_box');
    messageBox.append(message);
    $('body').append(messageBox);
    messageBox.fadeIn();
}

function updatess() {
     $.getJSON("php/fetch.php", function(data) {
       $.each(data.result, function(){
        var message = this['message'];
        addMessage(message);
  });
 });
}
```

Comment: If you want a new message box for each item, you'll need to create a new message box for each item. Take a look at my edit; let me know if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
 $('div.message').append( message );
```